# How to add data dynamically in structure which is a Pointer to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, structure

I have two structure as below:

```
typdef struct abc
{
   int id;
   char name;
}s_abc,*lpabc;
typdef struct result
{
    int acc_no;
    lpabc *details;
}s_res;
```

I need to dynamically add the data  within the structure result which points out to an array of pointers ie: `struct abc`
The structure `abc` could be an array of 5 values for eg.
How should i add the values ?

the structure defined are explicit:
For better understanding i'm attaching the structure below:-

```
typedef struct _wfs_cdm_physicalcu
{
    LPSTR                 lpPhysicalPositionName;
    CHAR                  cUnitID[5];
    ULONG                 ulInitialCount;
    ULONG                 ulCount;
    ULONG                 ulRejectCount;
    ULONG                 ulMaximum;
    USHORT                usPStatus;
    BOOL                  bHardwareSensor; 
 } WFSCDMPHCU, *LPWFSCDMPHCU;

typedef struct _wfs_cdm_cashunit
{
    USHORT                usNumber;
    USHORT                usType;
    LPSTR                 lpszCashUnitName;
    CHAR                  cUnitID[5];
    CHAR                  cCurrencyID[3];
    BOOL                  bAppLock;
    USHORT                usStatus;
    USHORT                usNumPhysicalCUs;
    LPWFSCDMPHCU         *lppPhysical;

} WFSCDMCASHUNIT, *LPWFSCDMCASHUNIT;
typedef struct _wfs_cdm_cu_info
{
    USHORT                usTellerID;
    USHORT                usCount;
    LPWFSCDMCASHUNIT *lppList;
} WFSCDMCUINFO, *LPWFSCDMCUINFO;
```

Here i need to access the data of _wfs_cdm_physicalcu 4 times ie : an array.

Comment: Since this is C++ I would suggest you use a vector instead of dynamic arrays.

Comment: Why is it pointer to pointer at first place. Consider changing it to just pointer or some C++ container unless required explicitly by design.

Comment: I completely don't understand what you are trying to do... `details` is a pointer to an array and you want to have many `abc`s? Or do you want to change number of fields in `abc`? This is completely confusing `lpabc *details;` why are you creating pointer to a pointer? Maybe try post code with semantics and syntax you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MohitJain :,I have posted the syntax for ref.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop using C idioms in C++; that only leads to confusion.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct abc {
    int id;
    std::string name;
};
struct result {
    int acc_no;
    std::vector<abc> details;
};
```

Now you can easily add as many `abc` values to the array as you like:

```
result r {42, {{1, "Mike"}, {2, "Fred"}}};  // inialise with two values
r.details.emplace_back(3, "Mary");         // add a third
```

Comment: @TechBrkTru: You don't, you access them through the vector. `r.details[1].name == "Fred"`.

Comment: Well in my structure... the first two values of struct _wfs_cdm_physicalcu remains constant and rest is dynamic .The address for this structure must be the same even if the "rest values" changes .Vector do use a dynamically allocated array to store their elements. But how about malloc.Since I have a linked structure eg: a -> b->c  and i need values of c to be present in "b" and the values of "b" in "a"

Comment: @TechBrkTru: "how about malloc" - like I said, don't use C idioms in C++. You could cobble something together with `malloc`, taking great care to avoid memory leaks and worse, but `vector` does essentially the same thing while managing all the memory allocations for you.

Comment: :What if there would another structure named for example : typdef struct data  {   int a ; char b  result res;} . Can we get the values of structure abc within  structure  data through vector??

Comment: @TechBrkTru: Yes, you can access class members in the usual manner. Given `data d;` you can access `d.res.details[2].name`.

Comment: :1)Well once i have assigned a hardcoded value in vector ,i cant dynamically change it. emplace_back is used to enter in the end –
2)an edit in the struct data :-- typdef struct data{int a ; char b ; std::vector<result> res; } ,so will the syntax be like this :- data d; d.res.details[1].name == "fred"; ?????
3)Also after i include the vector in my header file i get an error as "error C2894: templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage"

Comment: 1) Of course you can change it. Use `insert` or `implace` to add elements in other locations, and `erase` to remove elements. And of course you don't have to give it an initialiser; my example was just an example of some of the ways of initialising and manipulating it. 2) Yes, that's exactly what I said in the last comment. 3) So don't give it C linkage. Only do that for functions you want to call from, or implement in, C.

Comment: :1)Well for the above structures i edited my header file and in my cpp i edited it as follows
 WFSCDMPHCU lppPhysical;
WFSCDMCASHUNIT lppList;
WFSCDMCUINFO CashUnitInfo;
 
CashUnitInfo.lppList.lppPhysical[0].lpPhysicalPositionName == "C1"; 
CashUnitInfo.lppList.lppPhysical[1].lpPhysicalPositionName == "Ca2"; 

I'm facing an error :-error C2039: 'lppPhysical' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>' 2)Since the header file is a semantic one its is impossible for me  to change every line with the statement std::vector<> .
It is time consuming...

Comment: @TechBrkTru: If you have another question, ask another question. And try to use readable names (at least in the code you post; maybe you have a good reason for obfuscating your own code, but doing so here won't help people answer your questions).

Answer (score -1):

I think if you want to use malloc, you should define a pointer that points to the struct abc. Then if you find a new one you can malloc new memory and access it via the pointer. I also think the STL vector will be a better choice. It is very convenient. You can learn some knowledge about STL. That's so interesting.